# pip3 not working in python3.8.2

Tags: package-management, software-installation, python

I installed python 3.8.2 in my ubuntu OS which was preinstalled with python2.7 & python3.5

Using `update-alternatives` I was able to select the python version. 
Yet I am unable to install packages through pip.

When I tried using pip after I selected 3.8 version to install some packages, I get the following error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.cli.main'
```

I already have pip3 installed:

```
root@sv:/home/sv# apt install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Why would it work? What you get from the repositories is for Python 3.5.